# Issue with installing PHP from source with mysql

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I'm trying install PHP from source but i get below error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qkgB.jpg)

Command for configuring PHP:

./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Jay is right, lots of missing details here.  The error message is pretty clear, you need prerequisites here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a linux os but the error says you have to install perl first.
You can install from here: https://www.perl.org/
I guess you also have to activate/install apache to your computer.

Comment: Unless you are certain of the answer, post it as a comment.  Since you could not test it, this case applies here.

Comment: I actually wanted to post it as a comment but I do not have enough point to do that :) Sorry about that.